# How can you change the URL based on item selected in spinner with button click? Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner, openweathermap

I have one activity that has the button and another activity that opens once the user clicks the button. I am trying to create a new url to be opened in the second activity once the button has been pressed based on what is selected in a drop down.

First Activity

```
 btn_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(ACTIVITY_NAME, "User clicked Start Forecast");
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,
                   WeatherForecastActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 50);
        }});

  ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_entries));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        selectItem.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        selectItem.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Item one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cityPosition=0;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Item two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cityPosition=1;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Item three", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cityPosition=2;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Item four", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cityPosition=3;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }

                }
        );
    }
```

The second activity is opened after a button click and contains the url

```
 URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=city,ca&APPID=&mode=xml&units=metric");

                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
```

How can I change the value in q based on what is selected with the spinner in the first activity? 
Update

```
public class Weather{
 public  Integer cityPosition=0;
  btn_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(ACTIVITY_NAME, "User clicked Start Forecast");
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,
                    WeatherForecastActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 50);

                intent.putExtra("cityposition", cityPosition);
        }});
    public String getURL(){

String city ="vancouver";
        if(cityPosition==0) {


            city = "ottawa";


              }

        else if(cityPosition==1){

            city ="vancouver";

        }

        return city;
    }
```

Second Activity

```
StartActivity start;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_forecast);
start = new StartActivity();

         ForecastQuery f = new ForecastQuery();
        f.execute();

    }

    private class ForecastQuery extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {




        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + start.getURL() + ",ca&APPID=mode=xml&units=metric");
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("cityposition", cityPosition);

Comment: I added this to the button click event and it worked, but I only get the first value

Comment: What do you mean with the first value?

Comment: cityPosition=0, I will update my code

Answer (score 0):

```
String city = "Berlin";

if ( cityPosition == 1 )
  city = "Paris";

if ( cityPosition == 2 )
  city = "Madrid";
```

// and so on and you could have a string array for that

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + ",ca&APPID=&mode=xml&units=metric");
```

If there are spaces in the city name you have to url encode the querystring.

Comment: I tried that with my code above and it sets it to berlin, it ignores the listener

Comment: Then what was the value of cityPosition? What do you mean with 'it ignores the listener'?

Comment: In both activities you have a variable cityPosition. Please show how you instantiate it in the second activity.

Comment: the value is 0, and whenever I call the getUrl in place of where you have city, it just picks the first one, I click another option in spinner and it still shows the weather from the first cityPosition

Comment: The second activity doesn't have cityPosition, I will show what I use to get method

Comment: That url is in the second activity and all the code i posted too. The second activity should know the value of course. You put the value in the first activity in the intent. In the second activity you will extract the value from the intent.

Comment: Your suggestions did help once I realized in the first activity I  put the intent.putExtra before startActivityForResult